# Is there a way to determine at runtime if an object was created using Lambdaj.on() method?

Tags: java, lambdaj

I want to write a method that takes as a parameter either result of Lambdaj.on() call or a string.

```
public static <T> void method(T arg) {
}
```

`T` can be String here.
Is it possible to determine if arg was created using Lambdaj.on() method?

Comment: Does `Lambdaj.on` ever return String?  If not, and `!(arg instanceof String)`, then it came from `Lambdaj.on` (or is null).

Comment: Yes, `Lambdaj.on` can return any type. This is really cool because you can write `on(SomeClass.class).getX().getY()`

Comment: Then you can't, because if you receive a String it might be a String the user passed in directly or a String returned by `getY()`, and any information about the source has been lost.  (On the other hand, if `getY` actually returns a type that subclasses String and adds some interfaces, you can test for the presence of those interfaces.  That seems impossible without a modified JVM, however, as String is final.)

Comment: If I recall correctly, Lambdaj remembers returned values internally. If it uses identity comparison for strings I could check if `arg` is stored in Lambdaj internals (most likely by trying to pass `arg` to some Lambdaj method). But I don't know if it's safe or correct or defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Lambdaj source code ([ArgumentsFactory.java](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/ch/lambdaj/function/argument/ArgumentsFactory.java) for the most part) I can conclude that this is impossible.

Lambdaj stores data in a `WeakHashMap<Object, Argument<?>>`, where key is what return things like `on(SomeCLass.classs).getX()`.
WeakHashMap compares objects using `.hashCode()` and `.equals()`.